# Wildcard phrases with slop using string query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic supports slop for simple phrases, like `"quick fox"~2`, but when wildcards are used in string, it doesn't work: `"qui* fox"~2`

I've found a workaround for this using json query dsl using span_near and match prefix: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/146vmnsj7r/workaround-for-using-wild-cards-in-phrases-and-proximity-searches-elastic-search

The thing is that I must allow users to make such queries using string query. Is there any other workaround that uses just query string syntax or maybe there's some way to extend query string syntax for this specific use case?

Thank you

Comment: I have been looking for a workaround for this problem for so long. Thank you!